# Can we redirect to another url using Aspnetcore Backend? It is Possible or not? if it is possible means what is the correct way to do that?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Can we redirect to another url using Aspnetcore Backend? It is Possible or not? if it is possible means what is the correct way to do that?

```
  public void onlinePaymentForDonations()
{

        Response.Redirect("https://www.w3schools.com/");

        Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

        return;
}
```

Comment: What is onlinePaymentForDonations? Is it a controller method or what?

Comment: It is an Controller Post method..

Comment: You might want to look at the Redirect helper methods in the base controller class.  You might also want to look at the correct way of configuring CORS: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: Do you want to fetch data on behalf of the front end or send the front end to another place?

Comment: You can try like this  `return Redirect("https://www.w3schools.com");` Incase of simple redirect, but if there is any data transaction then need to do another way.

Comment: In Backend, It is Correctly redirecting.. but In  frontend, browser blocks..Because of same origin policy..

Comment: What kind of `frontend` you are using?

Comment: @Md Farid Uddin Kiron ..I am using React js..

Comment: So I think you have to handle it there, but in `asp.net` you can use simply this `return Redirect("https://www.w3schools.com");`

Comment: @Llama I tried this documentation also...For backend it is ok..But for frontend...Cross origin is not allowed...

Comment: And for the record: cross origin absolutely is allowed. You just need the server to send a header that authorises the origin you're coming from. What on Earth do you think you're doing here: `Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`???

Comment: @CaiusJard send the front end to another place.

Comment: @Llama can you tell me how to add in frontend?let config = {
  headers: {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  }
}postWithOrigin: (url: string, body: {}, headers:{}
    
  ) => axios.post(url, body, headers).then(responseBody),..I tried this..But this also not working for me..

Comment: You don't add it in the frontend. When you make an XHR request, the browser first creates an OPTIONS method request, in which it sends a header: `Origin`. The server must respond with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header that indicates the origin is allowed. If the server's response is invalid, the browser will not make the actual request (be it GET, POST, etc.). If the response is valid, the browser will make the request, but with the same Origin/Access-Control-Allow-Origin check as OPTIONS, so the browser can still fail the response if the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is wrong here.

Comment: In short: if you set up the server's CORS rules correctly, it will respond in the correct way, and the client will work. Example: if your website is hosted at https://www.example.com and your API is at https://myapi.microsoft.com then your frontend will send `Origin: https://www.example.com` and the server must respond with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.example.com`. The documentation for setting up support for this in ASP.NET Core is the one I already provided: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Comment: @Llama.. Yes..All you are saying is correct..I am trying to Integrate payupayment gateway..So only i am trying to redirect that site..That is different from my origin...i.e localhost:3000...So the browser network tab error is saying i am missing an header.."CORS mising allow origin"... This is the error....So here i am missing header while redirecting to payment site..What is i am missing and how i can add that?

Comment: Look at the origin header on the failing request.